# Prefab values resetting during runtime

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, prefab

I have a prefab `Block`. In my scene hierarchy, there is a lot of Blocks:

[image]

The prefab contains a code that contains an integer value called `id`.

I wrote a script (to run in edit mode) that sets random values to the `id` of all blocks and it works well, but when I hit play, all `id`s go back to 0. If I set the `id` manually in inspector, it stays correct during runtime.

What is this problem? Any ideas on how I can fix?

---

I tried to use things like `PrefabUtility.RecordPrefabInstancePropertyModifications` but it didn't work (or I don't know how to use it correctly).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it by using `EditorUtility.SetDirty(blocks[i])` in the for loop where I was setting the ids of the blocks.

After doing this, the values were maintained.